# Error 500 : The page cannot be displayed. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

> 2016-12-30 02:27:09,458 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-14] ERROR ApiMgtDAO Unable to find the API: admin-common7-1.0.7 in the database
>   2016-12-30 02:27:09,460 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-14] ERROR index:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Unable to find the API: admin-common7-1.0.7 in the database
>   2016-12-30 02:27:09,461 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-14] ERROR WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "apis" from null (/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag#40)
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "apis" from null (/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag#40)
>
> Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "apis" from null (/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag#40)

I restart wso2server.sh In AM. Then I can not successfully login the publisher site of AM.  The browser prompted as the following

> Error 500 : The page cannot be displayed.
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

why?

Comment: What is the error in logs you see after restarting?

Comment: There is no error logs but the logs as the following
>Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
 at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPool keObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
 at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

However, There are alse the logs before.

Comment: api stroe and carbon site can be loggined..

Comment: that connection error is not related to this. this can happen if you have put some invalid data when creating API. you may try cleaning database or, use REST APIs to to delete `common7` api.

Comment: You are right. But how can I clean the database or use REST APIS to delete common7 API?

Comment: are you using default h2 database or anything else? 
for REST APIs see https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/#guide and
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIIndividual#apisApiIdDelete

Comment: I think I use the default database. like this :
>-rw-rw-r--  1     1630208 Dec 30 02:47 WSO2AM_DB.h2.db
-rw-rw-r--  1          99 Dec 30 02:47 WSO2AM_DB.lock.db
-rw-rw-r--  1     4265984 Dec 30 02:55 WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db
drwxrwxr-x  2        4096 Dec 30 02:47 WSO2CARBON_DB.lobs.db/
-rw-rw-r--  1          99 Dec 30 02:47 WSO2CARBON_DB.lock.db
-rw-rw-r--  1      96256 Dec 30 03:19 WSO2MB_DB.h2.db
-rw-r--r--  1   753901568 Dec 30 03:29 WSO2METRICS_DB.h2.db
-rw-rw-r--  1         128 Dec 30 02:48 WSO2METRICS_DB.lock.db

Comment: Remove all in `repository/database/*` and restart server with `./wso2server.sh -Dsetup`. This will clean all your API/App/User data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131880/discussion-between-mike-and-bhathiya).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your common7 API is not properly created. Try to remove it from registry and see if you can login to publisher.

Comment: Your APIM is publicly accessible which is not good att all. And I just used it to help you. I removed common7 API, and now you should be able to access publisher.

Comment: I removed it from registry.

Comment: But ,firstly, Can you  login the publisher site successfully before having removed the API?

Comment: No, I couldn't.

Comment: Then how do you removed it from registy?

Comment: from registry browser in admin console (/carbon). see image in http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2014/01/wso2-is-and-am-share-registry.html